# Require.js optimizer - Trouble getting going

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

Good morning,

I have been messing around with the Require.js optimizer this morning and was having trouble getting started.

I am running windows 8, and have created a modular backbone.js application that I am now ready to package for deployment (production).  I would now like to optimizer theses files (concat and minimize), r.js optimizer seems like just the trick.

The problem I am running into is when trying to run the classpath command.

```
java -classpath path/to/rhino/js.jar;path/to/closure/compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r.js main.js
```

Will throw an error - Error: Could not find or load main class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main

I'm confused because I'm not sure where that package is even supposed to be, wouldn't it already be part of the optimizer/compiler?

My directory structure is as follows

```
build - 
compiler.js
js.jar
r.js

app
js -> backbone and application files here
css
images
```

I'd highly appreciate any light that could be shed on this one, this is the first time I am running the require.js optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you used attempts to run `r.js` with `main.js` as the entry point, not perform optimization (bear in mind the Optimizer is not the main component of `r.js`). You probably found the command in the [r.js README](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js); the correct command is in the same file, in the "Optimizer" section:

```
java -classpath path/to/rhino/js.jar;path/to/closure/compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r.js -o path/to/buildconfig.js
```

You'll need a build profile file which should be fairly straightforward in your case. More info directly on [RequireJS page](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics).

I can highly recommend using `Node.js` instead of Rhino, it's much faster and saves setting up Java dependencies/classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the information, after dabbling with this for a few hours yesterday I ended up trying node.js and immediately fell in love.  After creating a proper build file it just worked on the first shot.  Now I am tweaking and getting it to do exactly what I need it to do.